# Specific reduced expression of elements in $S_n$ ($W_{B_n}$)

Tags: permutations, coxeter-groups

I observed that if we consider elements in $S_n$ as permutations, for example we can write $$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &4 \\
4 &3 &2 &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\sigma$ has a reduced expression $s_3s_2s_1s_3s_2s_3$, which starts with a string $s_3s_2s_1$ that permutes 1 to 4.
I have a strong confidnec that this is true for any element in $S_n$ or $W_{B_n}$, however I don't know how to prove that. Any help would be appreciated.
To state the property formally:
For any $\sigma\in S_n$, it must have a reduced expression starting with $s_{\sigma(1)}s_{\sigma(1)-1}\cdots s_1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It would be good that you tell us what $S_n(W_{B_n})$ is.

Comment: are the $s$ the generators of $S_n$? the transpositions?

Comment: $S_n$ is the usual symmetric group, or you can say Coxeter group of type A.
$W_{B_n}$ is the Coxeter group of type B, sorry if the paranthesis has made confusions

Comment: Yes, those s_i are the generators.